# Is there a better way to create a Rails subclass?

Tags: ruby, callback, ruby-on-rails-4, single-table-inheritance

My single table inheritance system creates it's subclasses based on a input string from my service. I am wondering if there is a better way to write this code as it seems clunky.

The client should not know, nor should it care, what my sub-classing structure is. When a request comes in the parameters I get are:

```
{calculator: {course: 'science'}}
```

The class:

```
class Calculator < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :subclass, on: :create

  def subclass
    case course.downcase
    when "science"
      self.type = "Calculator::ScientificCalc"
    when "standard"
      self.type = "Calculator::StandardCalc"
    end
  end
end
```

It seems smelly to have a callback on the object and then set the 'self.type'. Any body have a better solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if I get what you want to do there, but you should create a type column on your calculator table, and your classes will inherit it from Calculator.

Comment: The type column is on the table already. I don't want my clients to submit their parameters as anything more than a 'course' name in this case.